# Google Apps Script onEdit() trigger not executing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon, google-apps-script-editor, gs-installable-triggers

I have been implementing a spreadsheet for about a year and a half now that constantly runs a number of trigger based GAS functions to check data, send emails based on that data, and update a staff calendar.

All of the time driven triggers are executing normally. I have not had an issue with them. However, the spreadsheet driven triggers (onEdit, onChange) are not working at all. I left work for a two week vacation and I did not change the script at all. When I came back, it no longer worked.

I deleted the trigger, recreated it, and switched between onEdit and onChange; the trigger will still not fire. The function that is triggered on edit is dependent on the event for it to execute properly. I test ran the function outside of the trigger and it failed where I expected it to (where the event dependant variables are) so there was no surprise there.

As far as I can tell, the spreadsheet driven triggers just won't fire at all. Does anyone know of any issues on Google's end, are spreadsheet driven triggers working for any of you guys? As far as I can tell the trigger just stopped working all together.

If I explicitly nest my function inside the onEdit() function in the script, it will execute, it won't if I just create a trigger, however it throws an error saying that the script does not have the permissions to execute MailApp.sendEmail() even though the app is already authorized to send emails as me.

Even more interesting, the functions executed with time driven triggers are still able to send emails and update my calendar.

It seems like the spreadsheet driven triggers have quit working all together.

*Just to be clear I did not make the mistake of naming my function onEdit or onChange.*

Comment: installed triggers have permission to send emails (and other stuff) since they were given express approval by the installing user. Simple triggers (functions with reserved names like `onEdit` or `onOpen`) do not have permission to send emails, so it is 100% expected that you receive that error when your function is called via the simple trigger `function onEdit(...` You haven't yet specified the action that is performed that you expect to activate your installed triggers, so please do so.

Comment: Thank you I did not know that about the permissions. The real issue is that the installed triggers from the sheet such as onEdit and onChange won't fire at all. It is as if they were never created then suddenly they will start working again, or they will work intermittently for the same exact unchanged functions across multiple sheets. The time driven triggers all work normally. I went on the google issue tracker to submit a ticket and I found that about 7 other people also submitted tickets reporting the same bug. Google may or may not be working on the back end to fix this issue.

Comment: Yes this is a definite issue for some users that's easily tested for those affected (under view ->executions in the script editor, onEdit() will fire but the custom installable trigger based on onEdit() only does sporadically. For me it started happening after some heavy spreadsheet functions (not scripted), so I thought it was just Google teaching me a lesson. The last issue submission was https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/125166462 and there were some others as well like you said: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%2B%20status:open%20installable%20triggers.

Comment: Do you have one or more scripts that are changing your document or script properties using `PropertiesService`? I had a similar issue, but it went away so I can't test it and prove it's the problem until I see it again. I'm thinking that running a script with `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().deleteAllProperties()` may solve the problem (at least temporarily). Also, you may want to check that everything you're writing to properties is properly formed. I did find in my code I was storing objects instead of strings and I fixed that. So far, hasn't repeated but I haven't tested long.